# MVCContrib - What's the best way to test XMLResult?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib

I am just getting going with MVCContrib. I have a controller action that returns an XMLResult. I would like write unit tests around the XMLResult. I have never used the MVCContrib's TestHelper. How can I get the resulting XML from XMLResult to test? Do I need to mock out the HttpContext obj?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the following action:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyViewModel
        {
            Name = "hello"
        };
        return new XmlResult(model);
    }
}
```

you could:

```
// arrange
var sut = new HomeController();

// act
var actual = sut.Index();

// assert
actual
    .AssertResultIs<XmlResult>()
    .ObjectToSerialize
    .ShouldBe<MyViewModel>("")
    .Name
    .ShouldEqual("hello", "");
```